# TinyMCE rich-text editor ads <p><br /> after the user presses Enter

Tags: tinymce, richtextbox

When the user presses enter, I expect a new paragraph to be inserted into the text. But for some reason, every time I press Enter, the system ads `<p><br />` into the HTML of the text, and it appears as though there are two lines in the text.  So there is extra horizontal white line.

Does anyone know how to prevent that for the users? I think it is very confusing to them.  An example page where this happens is here:

http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=181

See right below the initial paragraph how the result looks. Also, on the right side there is a link to edit the content so you can see for yourself how weird the input of new lines behaves.

Thanks ahead for your suggestions!!

Answer (score 1):

The `br` gets inserted because without it you would not be able to click into it using Firefox and could therefor not insert any text.